# "pip install tox" giving Found existing installation: filelock 2.0.12

Tags: pip, tox, filelock

I am getting following output.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HYpN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pip install -U --ignore-installed filelock
```

to overwrite existing non-pip installed module. After that repeat `pip install tox`.